# Multidimensional Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have in php a multidimensional array like this:

```
$personArray = [
              0 => 
                [
                  'Name' => 'John',
                  'Age' => '28',
                ],
              1 => 
                [
                  'Name' => 'Peter',
                  'Age' => '22',
                ]
             ];
```

In blade view i do a `foreach ($personArray as $pa)` to saw for example all names (inside foreach i do -> `$pa['Name']` and we print all names). For now it is ok. But i need to use this same array in javascript. I do this: `var pArray= <?php echo json_encode(json_encode($personsArray)) ?>;` and make an alert and he show the array (in this time the array are "converted" to javascript). But i need to make a foreach in javascript like i do in php to show in javascript all names inside of array. But i dont fine any solution.

I am not an expert in web programming so I thanked your help.

Thanks :)

EDIT: I have this array inside a php function on php class. I do return the array to the view that i need the array (Two view in this case..1st case i use the array in php with blade.. in the second case i use the array in javascript)

Comment: Look at 1st example in [`Array#forEach` help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Are you using laravel framework

Comment: Yes, i m using laravel :)

Comment: Their is a better way to do please refer this link https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/laravel-application-development/9781782162827/ch08s03.html

Comment: @RMaster21 - it's not a good practice to mix javascript and php in together..

Comment: I have this array inside a php function on php class. I return the array to the view that i need the array (Two view in this case..1st case i use the array in php with blade.. in the second case i use the array in javascript)

Comment: @justrohu i know but i need to use my array with some informations inside them in external api that are write in javascript

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the json value to js, then parse it to array.

php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

js:

```
var array = JSON.parse(json);
array.forEach(function(value){
   console.log(value['Name']);
})
```

Comment: Hi @Kris Roofe . Thanks it helps me. But i have onother question. In this case how to access to a specific values of key? How to do this forEach and print all values of name key? I want to print all names (in this case John and Peter) with foreach like i do in php code. Thanks

Comment: eidted, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is your friend.

In your case, you can do something like :

```
pArray.forEach(function(item, index, arrayItSelf){
  //do something with item
});
```

Comment: This is a php array

Comment: @justrohu watch the question closer. OP stated that the array is encoded into JSON.

Comment: @RMaster21 can you tread us with some up votes :P and please choose a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse two times in php, your code must be

```
var pArray= JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($personsArray) ?>);
```

You encode your php array in json and then you decode in javascript

Comment: In my case (and i not understand why) i need do use the json_encode two times to work..like i post in example. Thanks